# How do I show/hide controls on page load based on a select with generic class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

I have a page with numerous instances of code that looks something like this:

```
<select name="color_type_name" class="color_type_select" id=$ >
    <option value="">no color</option>
    <option value="solid">solid</option>
    <option value="gradient">gradient</option>
</select>
<input name="color1" class="hide color_$" />
<input name="color2" class="hide color_$ gradient_$" />
```

These code blocks are dynamically generated and assigned names and ID's based on the name and ID that's passed to the function that generates the code so one ID might be header_bg and another might be content_bg and a third might be footer_bg.

The two inputs get dynamic classes as well, appending color_ and/or gradient_ to the select's ID. I do this because if the user selects solid for the color type, I hide the second color. If the user chooses no color, I hide both inputs. If gradient is chosen, I unhide everything. Here's the change function that works.

```
$('.color_type_select').change(function() {
  if( $(this).val() == 'solid' ) {
    $('.color_' + $(this).attr('id')).removeClass("hide");
    $('.gradient_' + $(this).attr('id')).addClass("hide");
  } else if( $(this).val() == 'gradient' ) {
    $('.color_' + $(this).attr('id')).removeClass("hide");
  } else {
    $('.color_' + $(this).attr('id')).addClass("hide");
  }
});
```

My problem is, I don't know how to initialize the controls on page load. Obviously if there were only one instance, I'd just use the ID, not the class. I'm doing that for many other situations, but in this case, I could have 4-6 color pickers on a page so using ID's is not efficient.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can trigger the change even manually, so that the change event handler will get executed and the input values will get set based the select element's values

```
$('.color_type_select').change(function() {
  if( $(this).val() == 'solid' ) {
    $('.color_' + $(this).attr('id')).removeClass("hide");
    $('.gradient_' + $(this).attr('id')).addClass("hide");
  } else if( $(this).val() == 'gradient' ) {
    $('.color_' + $(this).attr('id')).removeClass("hide");
  } else {
    $('.color_' + $(this).attr('id')).addClass("hide");
  }
}).change();//here trigger the change event
```